# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"})

Tags: machine-learning, python, cnn, supervised-learning

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

when running this code, error below is shown

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-f0c9fe095010> in <cell line: 5>()
      3               metrics=['accuracy'])
      4 
----> 5 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10,
      6                     validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
   1103     if not adapter_cls:
   1104         # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
-> 1105         raise ValueError(
   1106             "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: {}, {}".format(
   1107                 _type_name(x), _type_name(y)

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'str\'>"})'})
```

currently using CNN to train my model
also want to mention that I converted all the lists into np array

```
for category in class_names:  # Iterate over the list of category names
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = imread(os.path.join(path, img))
        img_resized = resize(img_array,(150,150,3))
        flat = img_resized.flatten()
        flattened_data.append(flat)
        images.append(img_resized)
        target.append(class_names)
```

Comment: You seem to have strings in the training data (likely in the `class_names` variable), which the network cannot train directly on. Try encoding the string values into number.